# yes or no output in python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I am new to python I am trying to code this, I am asking a question, hence the "Are you a mutant" and depending on if the user responds with a yes or no it should come up the respective output but it works only for yes but not for no. how do i make it work for the elif output?

```
print("Are you a mutant?")
answer = input()
if    'Yes':
    print("Your application to Xavier's School for Gifted Youngsters has been accepted")
elif 'No':
    print("Your application was not successful on this occassion")
```

`

Comment: Try doing if answer == 'yes'

Comment: @OmidCompSCI thanks it worked

Comment: No problem, if you believe this answered your question below, please accept it so others may use it as a reference to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the variable that stores the users input with the thing you are comparing it to. In this case using the ==. Below is revised code off your example:

```
print("Are you a mutant?")
answer = input()
if answer == 'Yes':
    print("Your application to Xavier's School for Gifted Youngsters has been accepted")
elif answer == 'No':
    print("Your application was not successful on this occassion")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write raw_input instead of input. 'Input' just takes the text value but 'raw_input'get the input as a string.
If you are using python2, then follow the code below:

```
print("Are you a mutant?")
answer = raw_input("Yes/No: ")

if answer == "Yes":
    print("Your application to Xavier's School for Gifted Youngsters has been accepted")
elif answer == "No":
    print("Your application was not successful on this occasion")
```

In python3 raw_input() was renamed to input(). Then follow the code below:

```
print("Are you a mutant?")
answer = input("Yes/No: ")

if answer == "Yes":
    print("Your application to Xavier's School for Gifted Youngsters has been accepted")
elif answer == "No":
    print("Your application was not successful on this occasion")
```